# Unable to log in linux server from windows 10 with ssh

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssh

Since a few months I can only access the server (Ubuntu 18.04) from my computer (Ubuntu 20.4). Any attempt to access from my other Windows 10 computers gives me an error.
From my Ubuntu 20.04 I normally access the server with a private public key, but I can also access the server with username and password. From the Windows 10 machines I used to access the server with username and password but this access stopped working and I have not been able to access again.

When I try to access from Windows 10 with a username and password, the log of the sshd service on the server gives me the following error:

**admin sshd[4682]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 ty=ssh ruser= rhost=99.10.207.48  user=webs**

**admin sshd[4682]: Failed password for webs from 99.10.207.48 port 56928 ssh2**

This is a new situation. Apparently nothing has changed. I am completely lost

Comment: The log is pretty straight forward? Are you sure it's the correct password? Have you attempted to change it to a new, known password?

Comment: Bingo!! I forget my colleague change the password when he lost the tablet in the train. Thank you!!

Comment: Don't share passwords. Use personal users and sudo to impersonate a common service account if needed.